# Replacing nested SELECT

Tags: postgresql, left-join, inner-join, right-join

How can I make postgreSQL query like this:

```
SELECT event_id, user_id FROM public."point" 
WHERE user_id = (SELECT id FROM public."user" 
WHERE email='test@gmail.com')
```

with `JOIN`statement and without nested `SELECT` statement. Above works but I think it is not optimal. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your particular case, this should work:

```
SELECT p.event_id, p.user_id
FROM public."point" p JOIN
     public."user" u
     ON p.user_id = u.id 
WHERE u.email = 'test@gmail.com';
```

In general, when switching between `JOIN` and `IN`, you need to be careful about duplicates.  So the general solution would be:

```
SELECT p.event_id, p.user_id
FROM public."point" p JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT u.id
      FROM public."user" u
      WHERE u.email = 'test@gmail.com'
     ) u
     ON p.user_id = u.id ;
```

But the `id` is probably already unique in `user`.

Comment: Yes this is ti, it works fine. `id` in `user` is unique. I didn't add `email` comparison with `WHERE` in the last part of the query. (... `ON p.user_id = u.id WHERE u.email = 'test@gmail.com'`). Thank you very much!